# Why is Netbeans suggesting I “Flip operands of the binary operators” in my Java code

Tags: java

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) && e.isShiftDown()) {
        msgSend.append("\n");

    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        sendMessage();
    }

    else if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_X) && e.isControlDown()) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: An edit changed `&amp;amp;amp;amp;&amp;amp;amp;amp;` to `&&`. Is this correct?

Answer (score -2):

It's probably because your logic here isn't optimal. This would be better I think:

```java
if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
    e.isShiftDown() ? msgSend.append("/n") : sendMessage();
} else if(...) {
    ...
}
```

also, if this is going to end up being a big block of if-else if, I would use a switch statement instead.

**edit:** just to add some more context. If you are going to be both filtering by key press AND what other keys like shift, ctrl, etc. are pressed while a key is pressed, you want to separate if's or cases based on type. i.e. You want each block to first filter by key press and then inside the block have blocks to check for shift and ctrl presses. This is instead of one huge else-if block which covers every case such as enter press, enter press + shift, enter press + ctrl.

psuedocode:

```
if(enter pressed) {
     if(control is down) {}
     if(shift is down) {}
} else if(space bar pressed) {
     if(control is down) {}
     ...
}
```

rather than:

```
if(enter pressed and control down) {}
if(enter pressed and shift down) {}
if(enter pressed) {}
```

Comment: It is code from my college project on chat messenger using java